# The animation in the hamburger menu is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I do not know why the animation for the hamburger menu is not working. I guess I have some issues with the javascript. Please help me. I tried everything but nothing happens.

JS (ES6)

```
document.querySelector('.nav_trigger').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });

    const navTrigger = document.querySelector('nav_trigger'); 
    const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
    
    navTrigger.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      nav.classList.toggle('nav--open');

    });
```

Comment: On the line starting with ‘const navTrigger...’ your selector is missing the period

Comment: Ok. You should also put your variables at the top and combine the two listeners into one.

Comment: Do I have to put this line nav.classList.toggle('nav--open'); to the first even listener? I'm sorry I am very new in JS.

Comment: You just need one listener. In words, you are trying to accomplish this: “When the user clicks on the element with the class ‘nav_trigger’, toggle the classes on these elements”